# How to resume file-copying where it left off -- Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm backing up data in a folder on my hard drive, to Google Cloud Storage.

I cleared browsing data in Chrome, and logged back into the Cloud Console in a different tab; then refreshed the tab that, in the bottom-right of my screen, showed which files were copied; which not done yet; and the file that was currently copying.

That back up status thing has disappeared now.

How do I get it to resume backing up where it left off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upload state in the Cloud Console exists only in your browser, not on the Google Cloud Storage server, and you deleted it when you cleared browsing data in your browser and refreshed the tab -- simply logging in again in a different tab cannot make it reappear.